# Performing a check when saving a model in Django's admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'd like to perform a check when saving a model via the django Admin panel. I thought about using `ModelAdmin.save_model()`, however, from the documentation it says:

> ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelAdmin.delete_model() must save/delete the object, they are not for veto purposes, rather they allow you to perform extra operations.

I need to perform a check to enforce time constraints, only if the model is being edited and in some case, I need to NOT perform the save. (e.g. If it's past midnight and the admin is trying to edit a model instance, I don't want to save the changes, and alert the admin that it's past midnight...)

What would be the best place to do that considering that ModelAdmin.save_model cannot veto the saving operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply create a modelform with normal validation via the `clean` methods, then assign that form to be used in the admin by doing `form = MyFormClass` inside the ModelAdmin class.

Comment: I'm probably missing something obvious, but is there a safe/reliable way of knowing if the model instance is being edited, or inserted in the ModelForm's clean method? I only want to enforce validation when editing.

Comment: You can check the value of self.instance.pk - if it has a value, it's an edit.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Django 1.2 you can use [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).

Comment: At that point you no longer have access to `request.user`, so it doesn't really help much depending on the validation you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really admin site specific, but [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods) describes how to override the save functions on a Model, which does allow you to prevent the Model from being saved.  Could be that there's a way to do what you want with this method.

EDIT:

I'm 100% speculating here, but maybe by doing something like this in admin.py you could allow it to be admin-specific.

```
from blah.model import * 

def newSaveFunction( self, *args, **kwargs ):
    doStuff

MyModel.save = newSaveFunction

admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

Comment: I thought about that, but I'm not sure how I could display an error message in the Admin area from there...

Comment: Yeah, that part I'm not so sure about.